# Что происходит в Oracle при выполнении DML?

Tags: база-данных, oracle, select, update

Я начинаю знакомиться с Oracle. Помогите, пожалуйста, подробно понять, что происходит в СУБД при выполнении какого-либо оператора DML?

Например, в sqlPlus выполняется "update table1 set field1='test_value' where field2 = 'goal';". По field2 есть индекс.

Тогда:

1. Oracle в Shared пуле проверяет, нет ли у него плана такого запроса.
2. Если нет, строит план, сохраняет его в Shared.
3. В итоге блоки с field2 = 'goal' считываются в буферный кэш.
4. В кэше блоки изменяются и становятся 'dirty' (в какой момент появилась запись в redo-логе и что его туда написало?)
5. Создается контрольная точка, LGWR убеждается, что данные этой транзакции надо сбросить на диск, DBWn записывает 'dirty'-блоки по этой транзакции на диск.

Правильно ли я поняла механизм? У меня получилось примерно такое представление после чтения статей и уроков в интернете. Буду благодарна за более подробное описание процесса и за указание моих ошибок.

Ссылки на статьи и заметки принимаются вместо ответов :) 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем как начать менять блок Oracle пишет его целиком в undo сегмент. в случае отката транзакции он восстановит блок от туда. после этого блок меняется и в буфера redo пишется информация, достаточная для повтора операции (какая точно я не знаю :( ) Процесс LGWR периодически сбрасывает буфера redo на диск, но он это делает независимо от процессов которые пишут данные. При commit транзакции БД не торопиться сбросить на диск блоки данных. Но LGWR при этом в обязательном порядке пишет на диск все, связанное с этой транзакцией, включая мету о ее завершении. Так же время от времени процесс CKPT создает контрольные точки, в которых он (через DBWR, LGWR) принудительно сбрасывает на диск все буфера, после чего он пишет информацию о контрольной точке в control file. Непосредственно к транзакциям контрольные точки отношения не имеют. Они служат для быстрого восстановления экземпляра после сбоя. По ним БД при старте определяет до какого момента все данные точно были сброшены на диск и начиная с какого места redo файлов надо начинать повтор изменений транзакций.

По первым двум пунктам, да, все так. С третьим ... можно по разному посмотреть, для одного блока все так, для всей транзакции в целом не совсем. Транзакция может быть большая, блоки будут читаться по мере необходимости и так же по мере необходимости будут сбрасываться на диск, что бы освободить место под другие, ставшие нужными, блоки. И при отсутствии индекса по полю field2 БД будет читать в кеш все блоки данной таблицы, что бы найти в них интересующие записи, после чего менять те блоки, где такие записи нашлись и помечать их dirty, а блоки в которых ничего полезного не оказалось будут быстрее вытесняться следующими.